# SSRS line chart report

Tags: sql-server, charts, ssrs-2012, linechart

I try to create SSRS line chart repor but I couldn’t create a chart that I need. 
Y axis must indicate percentage values(PCT_RFT). X axis must indicate time(TIME).  I want to indicate product name on line as a label.
You can see my data in the below screenshot:

[image]

I would like to create a line chart as below:
[image]

When I try to create a line chart, my chart seems like this:

[image]

As you see, the third data  "KH44899" is not showing on the chart.
Could you please help me, how can I create my chart as requiered?

Comment: What was wrong with the one you've already made on SSRS? Tell us the expressions you used for its settings

Comment: Line Charts don't work the way you need. They SUM/AVG a Category (WEEK in your case). The third one isn't showing because it's also WEEK 5. It's either showing an average or the FIRST one for the week. I can't think of a chart that works the way you want - a Scatter chart is probably the closest but it won't have lines.

Comment: Add PRODUCT as a series group